# Create list from string separated by tab

Tags: python-3.x

I want to create a list from the following string which is saved in a file:

```
neurovaultcols_050817   1073
neurovaultcols_050817   1606
```

here is the code:

```
repo_dataset=open("G:\\My Drive\\single.txt")
k=[]
for x in repo_dataset:           
    x.strip().strip("").split("\t")       
    k.append(x)
for b in k:
    print(b[0])
```

Now, when I use `print(b[0])`, I 'd like to see "aneurovaultcols_050817". And when I use `print(b[1])`, I want to see 1073, and 1606.
 but I only see the first letters:

```
n
n
```

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change to:

```
with open("G:\\My Drive\\single.txt", 'r') as f:
    k = [line.strip().split('\t') for line in f]

for b in k:
    print (b[0], b[1])
```

The issue lies with:

```
for x in repo_dataset:           
    x.strip().strip("").split("\t")       
    k.append(x)
```

Basically this is saying "for line (`x`) in your open file (`repo_dataset`), strip and split the line on tabs". That returns a list, but you **dont** capture it, then you append the full line to `k`. If we break it down:

```
for x in repo_dataset:
    # lets say 'x' is currently 'neurovaultcols_050817   1073'       
    x.strip().strip("").split("\t")
    # 'neurovaultcols_050817   1073'.strip() removes leading & trailing characters
    # 'neurovaultcols_050817   1073'.strip("") is not necessary
    # 'neurovaultcols_050817   1073'.split('\t') returns ['neurovaultcols_050817', '1073']
    #    but you don't store the list that gets returned so it does nothing essentially
    k.append(x)
    # k.append('neurovaultcols_050817   1073') is what happens
```

So afterwards, this is what `k` looks like:

```
k = ['neurovaultcols_050817   1073', 'neurovaultcols_050817   1606']
```

So the `for` loop gets `'neurovaultcols_050817   1073'` as the first `b`. Thus, a call to `b[0]` represents the `'n'` at the beginning of the string!

The change is very simple to your original code as posted (although I recommend my code):

```
repo_dataset=open("G:\\My Drive\\single.txt")
k=[]
for x in repo_dataset:           
    y = x.strip().split("\t") # change    
    k.append(y) # change
for b in k:
    print(b[0])
```

Comment: thanks, @pstatix So I just needed to open it in 'r' mode?

Comment: @nina_dev I've updated the post with a detailed explanation